# Is there a way, where i can add the anchors for signature and other fields into the template without adding recipient?

Tags: docusignapi

I am adding the recipient from my application, but to add the anchors, I have to give all the dimensions on the document, which is not good, if the document changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

every tab has to be associated with a recipient. 
What you can do in a template is leave the recipient information empty, just name it (we call this a "role") and then add tags (with anchor string) for this placeholder. Later you decide what is the real recipient name/email.

Hope that helps.